# Overlapping DIV

Tags: css, html, css-float

Can anyone tell me how to fix the DIV Overlap here

http://www.zomghentai.com/daiakuji-episode-7-sub/

The Video Source 1 and Video Source 2 buttons are overlapping on the title bar.

**Note, also, for some reason...if I put float:left; in the span.sources, the hyperlink on the buttons disappear, any thoughts on that?

Edit ** Problem has been fixed. I had to add Float left to a bunch of divs ones after another.

Comment: I can't see (or possibly don't notice) either of the problems you describe in the Linux versions of Firefox 3.5, Chrome Stable, or Opera 10.63. Could you elaborate on how you're getting the problem and post a screenshot?

Comment: I wish you would have placed "CAUTION: NSFW" somewhere around the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to position the two buttons relatively